# The efficient computation of the zeta function at even integers

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

It is commonplace (see for instance [this paper by McGown](https://wstein.org/projects/168/kevin_mcgown/bernproj.pdf)) to calculate the Riemann $ζ$ function at even integer values by using

- an approximation to the real value
- and the Staudt--von Clausen theorem.

My question is this: For the first item, why do we use the Euler product, instead of the definition of the Riemann $ζ$ function? The latter is, after all, a series. I would guess that the Euler product has a better convergence rate, but I don't see the proof just now.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean "even integers".